# Crash after isCurrentInputMethodAsSamsungKeyboard on a Samsung tablet

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I'm seeing a few crashes from a Samsung Galaxy Tab S tablet. All I have is the stacktrace, which doesn't help much:

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: get package info: Neither user 1110217 nor current process has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS.
          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
          at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.isCurrentInputMethodAsSamsungKeyboard(IInputMethodManager.java:1289)
          at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.isCurrentInputMethodAsSamsungKeyboard(InputMethodManager.java:2526)
          at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.updateSuggestions(Editor.java:3004)
          at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2873)
          at android.widget.Editor.showSuggestions(Editor.java:1995)
          at android.widget.Editor$1.run(Editor.java:1830)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

It's obvious that my app doesn't care about `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS`. The system ends up requesting that exception after `isCurrentInputMethodAsSamsungKeyboard`, which I've never seen before.

Any clues?

Comment: are you using the marshmallow version??

Comment: No, that device is running Android 5.0.2